# Arduino Mega Timer1 in pure C problem - doesn't work

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt

Does somebody know what can be wrong in this, where I try to set Timer1 interrupt in Arduino Mega in C code only. I'm trying CTC Mode and the purpose is LED blinking with 1[s] Period.

I work with documentation program doesn't work completely.

```
 #include <avr/io.h>
 #include <avr/interrupt.h>



 void setup() 
 {
   //LED -> PB7 (Digital pin 13 
     DDRB |= (1<<PB7); 

  //FCPU = 16MHz, Prescaler :256 | CTC
   TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12) | (1<<WGM12);
   TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A);  // Compare Match A interrupt allowing
     OCR1A = 62500;

    sei();
    }

  void loop() 
  {

   }

   ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
   {
     PORTB ^= (1<<PB7); 
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `main` procedure? For toggling you can use `PINB = _BV(PB7); // or (1<<PB7)`, for setting up timer you can use assigments directly, as you don't care about previous values...

Comment: Actually you _should_ use assignments. The Arduino core library configures timer 1 for its own purposes (for phase-correct PWM at 490 Hz), so you should set both `TCCR1A` and `TCCR1B` to whatever suits your application, and not rely on their previous values. Alternatively, if you are not using the core, you could write your own `main()`, which would skip the Arduino hardware initialization.

Comment: Btw the arduino IDE requires using setup() and loop() section as a main(). So you suggest using "=" instead of  "|=" regarding to preliminary arduino settings?

Comment: So that "pure C" doesn't really mean you have simple `*.c` file with everything? You have `*.ino` and you're just using registers directly? Then yes, you have to make sure everything for Timer1 is in correct states. For example all counters are configured to the 8bit fast PWM mode and setting `WGM12` doesn't change anything as it's already set.

Comment: Ok, ok. I catch it. To be clear. I'm want to code in pure C but using Arduino IDE. So It requires specific arduino's program structure with setup() and loop(). And apart from it, everything is as a normal pure C language, working with uC registers not with arduino's libraries. That's my purpose.

Comment: You wrote: “_the arduino IDE requires using setup() and loop()_”. No, the IDE does not require `setup()` and `loop()`, the Arduino core library does. You can use the Arduino IDE and write your own `main()` if you don't need the functionality from Arduino core. And that's the closest you can get to “pure C” with the Arduino IDE (but technically it's C++).

Comment: Edgar Bonet, Ok. But Is using just main() instead of setup() and loop(), possible with bootloader? Doesn't Arduino's bootloader need those 2 arduino's loops()? I'm not sure, I'm just asking. I need to programme via bootloader not via external programmator.

Comment: @M_K No, the Bootloader is completely unrelated to the main program. Bootloader waits short time to the control characters and if there are none, it just jumps to the address 0000H (there are few more steps, but that jump is the most important)

Answer (score 1):

> I work with documentation program doesn't work completely.

simple:

1) check out the datasheet;
2) identify those registers needed to get tmr1 to work;
3) set or clear, as appropriate, ***ALL*** bits that are needed. Do NOT rely on default values.
4) done.